# Boost.Python: is it possible to register a custom converter for non-specialized template?

Tags: python, c++, boost

Judging by all the docs and examples I've found by now, boost.python only allows registering converters for specific types, e.g. `std::vector<std::string>`. However, I still don't like the idea of manually registering every single kind of standard containers and other templates which I happen to use in an exported function (e.g. vectors of string/int/float/my_custom_class...).

So is there any known workaround or hack to register a to/from python conversion for a non-specialized template (i.e. `std::vector<anything>`, `boost::optional<anything>` etc)? It doesn't have to be pretty (from-python converters aren't already), but something working would be appreciated.

I remember doing this successfully for Lua with Luabind (though I've already forgot how exactly I did that), so it would be very disappointing if it's not possible for python.